# Postgres manipulating sequence for bulkinsert on multiple tables

Tags: django, postgresql, sequence

I am writing a migration script that migrates the data from one database to another database. The new DB schema is completely a different schema comparing to the old schema so I have to manipulate the data to a new format. To make the insertion process quicker I am doing bulk insert to the tables with the help of the Postgres copy function.

The problem here is tables have a relation with one another, assume Table A and Table B. Table B have an FK relation with Table A. In my case, I have to do a bulk insert on both tables. Doing bulk insert on Table A is fine but doing it on Table B is not possible because I don't know the FK id of Table A.

**The solution to the Above problem**

Calculating the total number of entries I wanted to do a bulk insert on Table A and allocating that numbers in the sequence using the `setval` method solves the problem. Now I have the pre-allocated id's which I can be used to bulk insert Table A and also can be used as the FK in Table B.

**The problem in the above Solution**

I have a Django App which do insert on both Table A and B, after the migration the Django still picking the id between from the allocated sequences id. Since the id is already available in Table A the insertion API is failing.

any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: Using pg_dump+pg_restore is not an option?

Comment: both the schemas are completely different, I have to manipulate the data to accommodate the new table structure. so that's not an option in my case.

Comment: First do a verbatim copy, using  pg_dump+pg_restore, maybe in a temporary (staging) schema, Do the conversion work from there into a fresh schema.(or: in-place)

Comment: that's how basically I wrote, it will first extract and put it in one format and then insert that format into the new schema. I have edited my question. I hope it will give better clarity on the issue.